# HTML/CSS Textarea height auto? Text is falling behind

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation with my textarea, I want to make the height equal to the height of the content.

```css
.form-style-4 {
    width: 550px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

}


    .form-style-4 input[type=submit],
    .form-style-4 input[type=button],
    .form-style-4 input[type=text],
    .form-style-4 input[type=email],
    .form-style-4 textarea,
    .form-style-4 label {
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
 
   .form-style-4 textarea {
        font-style: italic;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        background: transparent;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #83A4C5;
        width: 275px;
        overflow: hidden;
        resize: none;
        height: 20px;
    }
    
.form-style-4 textarea[name=jobdescription] {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class=form-style-4>
<textarea name="jobdescription" id="jobdescription"  readonly>Lorem ipsum, oh well nvm,Lorem ipsum, oh well nvm,Lorem ipsum, oh well nvm</textarea>
</form>
```

Now I have seen people doing this with a javascript function which is called with a onkeyup pressed. But that is not what I really want, I only want the textarea height equal to its content.

In javascript it would be something like

```
function adjust_textarea(h) {
    h.style.height = "20px";
    h.style.height = (h.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

But I guess this is possible just using Html/Css right?

Edit: This is not duplicated with this link. I am asking if it is possible to do this in html/css. The content of the textarea is from a database, it could be 1 line, but could be 4 lines as well. Is there nothing like height:auto; that could fix this? I would like not to use Javascript for this, as keypress is not relevant as this is a readonly textarea

Comment: How is this duplicated of that? I ask if this is possible with html/css only as the textarea is readonly, but the text comes from a database. the height of the content is not fixed. could be 1 line, but could be 4 lines as well

Comment: well then why you set a fixed height ( ` height:20px` )  to the text area ? just set `height:auto`  and it will have the height of it's content

Comment: is it? https://jsfiddle.net/822vbozw/3/ Already tried that

Comment: you really need to use a textarea ? or what you want is the content ( text added )  to be editable ?

Comment: if it is possible yes, it has to look like the other (mutable) textarea's and other input types

Comment: If it's readonly, just make it a div and style it, it will grow with content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but it's not possible with plain css to change the height of a textarea depending on its content. You will have to use javascript or give it a solid height and maybe a scrollbar, when to many lines are added.. :(

Comment: I think you're right, Guess I will need javascript but no idea how to do this onload. Oh well, time to google again :)

Comment: Yes Google is your best friend, there are many different good js/jquery solutions for that :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather you're trying to make it so that the textarea displays all of the text inside it - if so why not just add a rows attribute to your textarea tag? You also don't need to set a height

```
<textarea rows="3"></textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ouqe170/18/

Comment: That would have worked indeed if the content was always the same, unfortunately, in my situation it can be between 1 to 5 lines.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is another solution Using `<div>` and `contenteditable` attribute

```css
div{
  width:98%;
  min-height:50px;
  border:1px dotted black;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">Type text here</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This solved my problem:

```
function h(e) {
                $(e).css({ 'height': 'auto', 'overflow-y': 'hidden' }).height(e.scrollHeight -20);
                }
                $(".form-style-4 textarea[name='jobdescription']").each(function () {
                    h(this);
                }).on('input', function () {
                    h(this);
                });
```